# md-sidenav animation not disabling in IE?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

My CSS to disable the animation is as follows:

```
md-sidenav.md-closed-add,
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove,
md-sidenav.md-closed-add.md-closed-add-active, 
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove.md-closed-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-locked-open-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active

{
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none
}
```

This works perfectly fine for Chrome and Firefox as I don't see the animation. However, I can still the md-sidenav animation in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sidenav but your should probably disable the transition with the others prefix:

```
-o- Opera
-moz- Mozilla
-webkit- Webkit 
-ms- Microsoft
```

etc.